GA pageTracker is undefined
I am trying to download drivers from Dynabook, but there seems to be a GA-related issue.
The console provides the following errors:
pageTracker is undefined

and
pageTracker._trackEvent is not a function

It seems like the GA JS is failing to load and that is blocking the rest of the website JS from running. Is there a way around this?

I realised that my own empty function is good enough to solve this problem:
var pageTracker = {};

pageTracker._trackEvent  = function() { 
return 'Hello'; 
}

I ran this JS in the Firefox Dev Tools Console, and then i was able to download the drivers successfully.
If you have a 404 error, you can try inserting the download URL into the Internet Archive Wayback Machine.
